# FB auth.logout is being raised after being logged in using the "server-side-workflow" (OAuth 2.0)

Tags: facebook, authentication, logout, oauth-2.0

NOTE: Our (web) application was working fine until we upgraded to the Oauth 2.0 workflow this past weekend.

When a user "connects with facebook" to our (web) application we log them in to Facebook using the "server-side-workflow" described in the [Facebook Authentication docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). However, Facebook is raising the auth.logout event when the user gets to their home page in our application which contains the following javascript code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'XXX', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, channelUrl: 'http://XXX/fbchannel.html', oauth: true}); 
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        logout();
    });
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
function logout(){
    new Ajax.Request('http://XXX/logout');
}
```

It appears that while the user is logged into Facebook, they are not logged into our application (if you have facebook.com open in a 2nd tab of your browser and re-load the page after being logged in by our application you will see that you are indeed logged into facebook.com).

Is there an additional step in OAuth 2.0 that needs to be taken to log the user into our application when using the "server-side workflow" that wasn't necessary in the previous version of OAuth?  Does the user have to explicitly login via facebook after being connected?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Jason

PS- Logging into our application via the client side flow (after you've previously connected) works just fine.  It's only when connecting and being logged in via the server side workflow do we experience the auto-logout problem.

Comment: I was able to fix this problem by adding a call to FB.getLoginStatus in my auth.logout event handler and checking the response for an authResponse object.  I don't know why Facebook raises the auth.logout when FB.getLoginStatus returns an authResponse indicating that the user is logged in, but, it does. So, this is a hack:           FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
              FB.getLoginStatus(function(res) { 
                  if(!res.authResponse) { 
                      logout();
                  }
              });
          });

Comment: Great find! I wonder if it still occurs or if Facebook has fixed this...

Comment: I just started seeing this behavior in my application today as well. I came up with the same hack as you but I'm a little uncomfortable with it.

Answer (score 0):

For ajax pages you need to get the uid, access_token, and or code from the browsers session.

This is standard for iframes and ajax for clickjack prevention, and other security risks.
SEE: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.13

---

**QUICK AND DIRTY EXAMPLE:**

```
<?php
// be sure to exchange YourAppId, with your app id. 

if(isset([fb_YourAppId_user_id])){
$user = [fb_YourAppId_user_id];
}else { // no user, send to login flow. }

if(isset([fb_YourAppId_access_token])){
$access_token = [fb_YourAppId_access_token];
} else { // no user, send to login flow }

?>
```