# FaceBook FB.ui logout dont fire

Tags: facebook, logout, fb.ui

```
FB.ui(
       {
         method: 'feed',
         name: 'some text',
         link: 'some text',
         picture: 'aa.jpg',
         caption: 'some text',
         description: 'some text',
         message: 'some text'
       },
       function(response) {
         if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('Post was published.');               
        } else {
            alert('Post was not published.');
         }
       });
}
```

That code WORK fine, now i like after :

```
alert('Post was published.');
```

to be logged out from facebook, silently
HOW ?

Adding that code After the `alert('post publish')` did not do anything !!

```
FB.ui(
 { method:'auth.logout',  display:'hidden' },
 function() { alert("you're logged out!"); }
);
```

i have found : [FB auth.logout is being raised after being logged in using the "server-side-workflow" (OAuth 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637297/fb-auth-logout-is-being-raised-after-being-logged-in-using-the-server-side-work) but not sure i understand the code enough to know it do what i ask !

Comment: if your not using the button for logout then you will need to append an app access token to the logout url  "php-sdk"  I do not think it will work with javascript unless you build the logout url yourself.

Comment: interesting answer, but look like mumbojumbo to me... please provide me an example, some code please !... i am not that intelligent !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

> **Best Practices**
>
> FB.logout will log the user out of both your site and Facebook. You
>   will need to have a valid access token for the user in order to call
>   the function.
>
> Calling FB.logout will also invalidate the access token that you have
>   for the user, unless you have the offline_access permission.

**I wrote a sample using the comments box to fire the auto logout**
http://shawnsspace.com/fb.logout.test.php

THE CODE:

---

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>    
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
    appId  : '112104298812138',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    //channelUrl : 'http://WWW.MYDOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // channel.html file
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
        });
FB.Canvas.EarlyFlush.addResource("http://shawnsspace.com/index.php");
FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
              if (response.authResponse) {

                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
              } else {
              }
            }); 
    FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
     //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
        FB.logout(function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
        });
    });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        //top.location.href = 'http://apps.facebook.com/shawnsspace/fbcomments.php?ref=loggedin';
        window.location.reload();
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        //top.location.href = "http://apps.facebook.com/shawnsspace/fbcomments.php?ref=loggedout";
        alert('logged out');
        });
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
</script>
```

Comment: all the code is not needed, you can modify as you see fix, just wanted to show how it was done in the example i posted.